# Calculating rolling Beta

Tags: r, performanceanalytics, tidyquant, tibbletime

I'm trying to generate rolling betas for stocks and my rolling function is not working. What I have tried so far:

```
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)

ticker_data <- tq_get(c("AAPL", "SPY"))


daily_returns <- ticker_data %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = close, 
               mutate_fun = periodReturn, 
               period     = "daily", 
               col_rename = "daily_return") %>% 
  ungroup
  
all_returns_df <- left_join(daily_returns %>% filter(symbol == "AAPL"),
          daily_returns %>% filter(symbol == "SPY") %>% 
            select(-symbol) %>% 
            rename(mkt_daily_return = daily_return))



# Can generate one Beta for all dates
all_returns_df %>% 
  tq_performance(Ra = daily_return,
                 Rb = mkt_daily_return, 
                 scale = 252,
                 performance_fun = table.CAPM)


# Rolling Beta is not working

#Function that is not working
roll_beta <- rollify(.f = function(xy){ tq_performance(data = xy,
                                                       Ra = daily_return,
                                                       Rb = mkt_daily_return, 
                                                       scale = 252,
                                                       performance_fun = table.CAPM)},
                     window = 40)

# This fails
all_returns_df %>% roll_beta()
```

Any ideas on how to make this work for me?

My main aim is to do this in a "tidy" way.

Answer (score 1):

Note: tibbletime has been retired. You should look into timetk.

Now timetk has the `slidify` instead of `rollify` function. But I couldn't get it to work correctly as it keeps complaining about the period. But going back to `zoo::rollapply` does the trick. Also getting the whole table is for also an issue for some reason.

The code below will work for the example given and return the beta's. I'm using the function `CAPM.beta` to return the beta's.

```
CAPM_beta_roll <- function(data, width = 40) {
  data <- timetk::tk_xts(data, date_var = date)
  beta <- zoo::rollapply(data = data[, 1], 
                         FUN = CAPM.beta, 
                         Rb = data[, 2], 
                         width = width, 
                         by = 1, 
                         align = "right",
                         by.column = TRUE) 
  names(beta) <- "beta"
  out <- timetk::tk_tbl(beta, preserve_index = FALSE)
  out$beta
}

all_returns_df %>%
  mutate(beta = CAPM_beta_roll(.))

# A tibble: 2,680 x 5
   symbol date       daily_return mkt_daily_return  beta
   <chr>  <date>            <dbl>            <dbl> <dbl>
 1 AAPL   2011-01-03     0                0           NA
 2 AAPL   2011-01-04     0.00522         -0.000551    NA
 3 AAPL   2011-01-05     0.00818          0.00520     NA
 4 AAPL   2011-01-06    -0.000808        -0.00196     NA
 5 AAPL   2011-01-07     0.00716         -0.00196     NA
 6 AAPL   2011-01-10     0.0188          -0.00126     NA
 7 AAPL   2011-01-11    -0.00237          0.00354     NA
 8 AAPL   2011-01-12     0.00814          0.00902     NA
 9 AAPL   2011-01-13     0.00366         -0.00163     NA
10 AAPL   2011-01-14     0.00810          0.00724     NA
# ... with 2,670 more rows
Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `beta`.
i `beta = CAPM.beta_roll(.)`.
i Non-numeric columns being dropped: symbol, date
```

You can ignore the warning messages. These come from `time_tk::tk_xts`

For faster implementations of the function you can find several examples in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101871/capm-beta-rollapply).

Comment: Suggest `library(zoo);
betafun <- function(x) cov(Re(x), Im(x)) / var(Im(x));
all_returns_df %>%
  mutate(beta = rollapplyr(daily_return + mkt_daily_return * 1i, 40, betafun, fill = NA)`
Note the r on the end of rollapplyr.  Also we omitted arguments that are not needed because they are at the default values.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks. This is an awesome function. Would appreciate very much if you could also write out the functions for: (1) CAPM.beta.bull(Ra, Rb, Rf = 0) and  (2) CAPM.beta.bear(Ra, Rb, Rf = 0) for implementation in the same manner.

Comment: Try these where `betafun` defined in my last comment: `beta.bull <- function(x, s = x[Im(x) > 0]) betafun(s);
beta.bear <- function(x, s = x[Im(x) < 0]) betafun(s)`